# "PHP program not installed" message while installing ZF2 on ubuntu Xampp

Tags: php, installation, xampp, zend-framework2, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to install ZF2 on ubuntu Xampp. I am following :-

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

I have downloaded the zip file. But when I run the command

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

I get a message :-

"The program 'php' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install php5-cli"

If we are trying to install within xampp then why do we need to install php separately, shouldn't xampp handle this?

Thanks

Comment: PHP is not found by your system. But seriously, if you have a linux, why the EFF would you use xampp?

Comment: I had used Xampp in Windows, so I kept on using it even while I shifted to Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this fix it -> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1224146 (agree with @Sam though, a LAMP stack is easy to set up in Linux, especially Ubuntu)

Comment: I installed php, but now it lists lots of problem. Prblm 1 ;- The requested package php >=5.3.3 could not be found

Comment: Prblm 2 :- Installation request for zendframework/zendframework >2.1.3 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zendframework 2.1.4.
    - zendframework/zendframework 2.1.4 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.

Comment: What does `php -v` report?

Comment: the php version. it's crazy to use xampp on Linux :)

Answer (score 0):

Please Update/NewInstall your ubunto to latest version
and install php packages with apt-get command ... should fix your problem

You can verify php cli running by type this command in your console :

```
$php -v
```